# Ng-repeat e AngularJs erro de iniciante

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Estou iniciando no *angular* e ainda não entendo bem o *workflow* do mesmo. O código abaixo não funciona:

```
<body ng-app>
 ...
<div ng-controller="Grid" class="gol-grid">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in board track by $index">
            <div class="gol-cell" ng-repeat="gol-cell in row track by $index" ng-class="{alive: gol-cell.isAlive}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dúvidas  no *`ng-repeat="row in board track by $index"`* ele pegará cada item do scope *`row`* e adicionará a *div* com a classe *`row`*?

Segue o script js

```
function Grid($scope) {
var SIZE = 50;
$scope.board = [];

function Cell(x, y, alive) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.isAlive = alive;

}

for(var i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
        row.push(new Cell(i, j, Math.random() > 0.5));
    }
    $scope.board.push(row);

}
}
```

E o css:

```
.gol-grid{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.gol-cell{
    margin: 0; padding:0; border: 0; display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; height: 10px;
}
.alive {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.row{
    line-height: 0;
}
```

No *firebug* aparece

`[ngRepeat:iidexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ngRepeat/iidexp?`

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

1. `ng-repeat="row in board track by $index"`

   A cada item dentro do array **board**, será criado uma nova `<div class="row">` e uma nova `<div class="gol-cell"..... </div>` ou seja, tudo o que você colocar dentro da div do `ng-repeat`, será criado a cada row. Se você tem 10 itens, 10 divs serão criadas.
2. `ng-repeat="gol-cell in row track by $index"`

   A cada item dentro do array **row**, parece que você não está criando nada. E adicionar "**-**" (hifen) em nome de variaveis nunca foi algo correto Tente colocar o nome da variavel dentro das normas, exemplo: **golCell**.

Talvez o erro seja este. Poste feedback.

Comment: No item 1, a div que será repetida é a `<div class="row">`.

Comment: Verdade, e a gol-cell.

Comment: Obrigado @lordcheat. Ficou bem claro sua explicação. Estava confundindo o nome das classes com o nome das arrays. :) Seguirei sua dica.